# How can i check if user's tweets are protected via ajax without triggering a login dialog?

Tags: jquery, ajax, twitter

For example, say I was using the twitter widget here:

http://twitter.com/about/resources/widgets/widget_profile

And I was filling in the input automatically and pulling tweets using javascript.  If I do this on page load for a twitter username with protected tweets, the dialog will ask me for a username and password.

Is there anyway to prevent this from happening.  Like to somehow check in the background using only javascript is the tweets are protected without triggering this dialog.

Using the oAuth isn't an option here.

Thanks!

EDIT:

```
var twitter_url = "http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?&screen_name=" + twitter_handle + "&count=20&callback=?";

$.getJSON(twitter_url, function(data){ 
    loadtwit(data);
});
```

But if the response is a prompt for a username and passowrd rather than a successful return of the user json, i'd like to kill the request.  I'm not sure how to do that.  Thanks.

Comment: The author for that widget is Dustin Diaz (dustin@twitter.com). Maybe try emailing him and requesting an option for the widget to return something if an account is protected or whether to ignore authorization dialogs/etc ?

Comment: I guess my question isn't specific to the widget.

I want to do this:

var twitter_url = "http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?&screen_name=" + twitter_handle + "&count=20&callback=?";

$.getJSON(twitter_url, function(data){ 
             loadtwit(data);
});

Comment: sorry can't write code in comments

Comment: So if you put a protected username in the api call, you will get a username and password dropdown dialog.  Otherwise you will get the api response with the tweets.   How can I prevent the dialog?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the users/show method(http://dev.twitter.com/doc/get/users/show) like:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://api.twitter.com/1/users/show.json?screen_name="+twitter_handle,
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    success: function(data){
        console.log(data.protected);
    }
});
```

`data.protected` is true if the user profile is protected.